# How to add a class to the body that will change depending on the page in the remix?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags, remix.run

The body is located in the root.jsx, where I want to give it a parameter as class that will change depending on the page. In the route on each of the pages I want to assign values, for example the class on _index is equal to “company homepage”, in restaurants route the class is equal to “venue company” and so on. Is it possible to transfer parameters from routes to root.jsx?

root.jsx

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <head>
        <meta charSet='utf-8' />
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' />
        <link rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com' />
        <link
          rel='preconnect'
          href='https://fonts.gstatic.com'
          crossOrigin='anonymous'
        />
        <link
          href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:wght@100,300,400,500,700&display=swap'
          rel='stylesheet'
        />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

_index.jsx

```
export default function Index() {
  const { startPage } = useLoaderData()
  const page = startPage.page.sections;
  return (
    <main id='main'>
      <PageComponents page={page} />
    </main>
  );
}
```

restaurants.jsx

```
export default function Restaurants() {
  const { restaurants } = useLoaderData();
  return (
    <>
      <PageComponents page={restaurants.sections} />
      <footer className='footer' />
    </>
  );
}
```

PageComponents.jsx

```
import loadable from "@loadable/component";

const components = {
  logo: loadable(() => import("./Logo")),
  intro: loadable(() => import("./Intro")),
  languageSwitch: loadable(() => import("./LanguageSwitch")),
  venueGroup: loadable(() => import("./VenueGroup")),
};

export default function PageComponents({ page }) {
  return (
    <main>
      {page
        .filter(({ type }) => !!components[type])
        .map(({ data, type }) => {
          const Component = components[type];

          return (
            <div key={type}>
              <Component data={data} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Tried function loader in root.jsx to get the API for each page and added a variable to body className, but sometimes there are going to be no data about pageClassName, so I need to pass parameter about className manually to each page from the routes and transfer this parameter to root.jsx

Answer (score 0):

The simple way would be to introduce an object where there a mapping of CSS file and the url path, then you can use `useLocation` hook to check which child component is being rendered.

```
import { useLocation } from "@remix-run/react";

function SomeComponent() {
  const location = useLocation();
  // ...
}
```

You can swap the CSS file link. But I would recommend not to change CSS from the parent itself. Just add different CSS files to the respective component. If you update the CSS file on the parent every time a child component is being rendered then it will affect the performance of the app, and goes against the performance tuning React provides. And if it's a same website, just different child pages then you would always like to keep the parent's theme like Header and Footer consistent across the app which is good as per the design principle.